# ClassNotFoundException with Installer built using install4j

Tags: install4j

The installer built with install4j 6.1.6 is generating the below error. any suggestions on what could be causing this issue?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.client.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:62)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher$2.run(WinLauncher.java:96)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Java invocation" step of the launcher wizard, you have to configure the class path, including the archive or directory containing the class `com.test.client.Main`.